# Chrome - eval() in context of iframe from WebExtension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a WebExtension that scrapes some data from a web page. The page in question dynamically loads stuff into an iframe, and the iframe contains the stuff I need. The data I need never gets written to the iframe document, it only exists in the JS objects.

From inside of my WebExtension, I'm trying to do the following:

```
var result = $("iframe")[0].contentWindow.eval("(function() { return $('#grid').jqxGrid('getrows'); }())");
```

This works flawlessly when using the extension in Firefox. No issues whatsoever.

Unfortunately, trying to do the same thing in Chrome results in the error `$ is not defined` on the eval.

I've been trying for the last couple of hours to figure out why and I'm at a complete loss. Would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Which part throws the error? The first `$` or the second?

Comment: @CertainPerformance It errors on the eval.

Comment: It might be that jQuery hasn't loaded in the iframe by the time you try to call it. Maybe see if a `setTimeout` works?

Comment: Nah, it's definitely loaded. If I open up dev tools and run `$('#grid').jqxGrid('getrows');` in the context of the iframe it runs just fine, but then I click my button and I get the error.

Comment: Wild guess, maybe try explicitly referencing `window.$` or `window.jQuery`

Comment: No dice. Would be nice if the solution were that simple.

Comment: [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Comment: @wOxxOm I had a similar thought yesterday just before I left. I was able to inject a script block into the iframe and have it get the data successfully. Only problem is getting that data back out to my extension. I guess I could just stringify it and stick it in a hidden field or something.

Comment: The usual method is dispatchEvent of CustomEvent from the page script to the content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ah, yeah, that makes sense. I had tried that previously with no luck, but I was using `window.dispatchEvent` and it wasn't catching my event, but changing it to `top.dispatchEvent` did the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why the `eval()` works in Firefox but not in Chrome, but here's what I ended up doing to get what I needed:

1) Add an event listener in my extension for a custom event.

```
window.addEventListener("myCustomEvent", function(e) { HandleResult(e.detail); });
```

2) Inject a script block with the code to fire the event, including the data I need, into the body of the iframe document.

```
$("body", $("iframe").contents()).append("<script>top.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myCustomEvent', {detail: $('#grid').jqxGrid('getrows') }));</script>")
```

Shout-out to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for pointing my brain in the right direction.